# Xamarin Android equivalent "method", "property" or "class" of Android

Tags: android, xamarin

What is used in xamarin android in place of android code.
You may add your questions to this to make it more useful. Please answer if know equivalent the below method:

1. getResources()
2. getDisplayMetrics()
3. stringWithContentsOfFile("ReadMe.txt")

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `Context` instance then you can do this:

```
  1. Context.Resources
  2. Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics;
  3. System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Context can be obtained via `Application.Context` or an `Activity` instance

Answer (score 0):

Please add you answers in it.

Answer:

3. System.IO.File.ReadAllText("ReadMe.txt");

Answer (score 0):

When building your app with Xamarin.Android you actually use the exact same API's as you would normally if you develop for Android in Java. However, the API signatures have been C#-ified, to adhere to the naming conventions of the .NET platform. So the names are almost all the same, or equivalent in .NET as they are in Java.

Comment: Usually, it holds true, but exception always make there way